# Querying a complex Doctrine relationship with nested ManyToOne and OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a quite complex Doctrine relationship architecture that's been a headache to query. It is written like this:

**Project** `[OneToMany, Bidirectional]` **Milestone**

**Milestone** `[OneToMany, Bidirectional]` **Sprint**

**Sprint** `[OneToMany, Bidirectional]` **Ticket**

So, a Ticket has a direct dependency on a Sprint, but not a Project or a Milestone. It's almost like a Tree Hierarchy. It works great. However, i'm having serious problems on:

- How do i discover all tickets from a specific Project?
- How do i discover all tickets from a specific Milestone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Doctrine Query Builder you can get all tickets from a project like this:

```
$project_id = ...

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Ticket');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->join('t.sprint', 's')
                    ->join('s.milestone', 'm')
                    ->join('m.project', 'p')
                    ->where('p.id = :project_id')
                    ->setParameter('project_id', $project_id)
                    ->getQuery();
```

And this is how all tickets from a milestone can be retrieved:

```
$milestone_id = ...

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Ticket');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->join('t.sprint', 's')
                    ->join('s.milestone', 'm')
                    ->where('m.id = :milestone_id')
                    ->setParameter('milestone_id', $milestone_id)
                    ->getQuery();
```